# USB C default voltage output 5V?

Tags: usb, usb-c

I have a USB C powerbank and require it to power a "dumb" circuit, i.e. just a USB C connector with, for example some LEDs on it. There is no microcontroller.

I used a voltmeter and a USB C breakout board, connected to my power bank,  to see if there is any voltage on any of the pins. I got 2.3V on CC1.

Do I need to set up any PD options, e.g. just with pull up resistors to get 5V by default, e.g. on V BUS?

Comment: Yes, you need resistors as USB-C shouldn't supply Vbus until it sees a device connected. Have a look [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/333071/usb-type-c-configuration-necessary-for-battery-charging-only)

Comment: Put a 5.1K resistor from CC1 to ground and another 5.1K from CC2 to ground. That's enough to tell the Host something is hooked up and therefore to assert 5V on VBUS with a minimum capacity of 1.5A.

Comment: Many thanks to al!. I spent ages online looking for this.

Comment: USB-C default output voltage is Zero.

Comment: Great question! Too bad no one has seen fit to provide a proper answer - but at least you now know why.

Comment: @Seamus, there is nothing "great" in this question; the comprehensive answer is in USB Type-C connector specifications, in quite explicit form.

Comment: @Ale..chenski: It seems we have a difference of opinion. I do think it's a great question.;that you don't has no meaning for me.